# (symfony event dispatcher) when to dispatch an event?

Tags: symfony, event-dispatching

I'm using `Symfony EventDispatcher` in my project.

There is a trade/pay system in my project, user can create an `order`, the order's status is `unpaied`, when user paid the order by paypal, paypal will trigger a `trade finish hook`, my project's `PayNotifyController` will receive the hook.

So the question is, should I dispatch `pay.success` event when I receive the hook, or after update the order's status to `paid` ?

pseudo code:

```
public function hookAction() {
    $event->dispatch('pay.success');
}
```

then add a event subscriber to update the order's status to `paid`.

or

```
public function hookAction() {
    set_order_paid();
    $event->dispatch('pay.success');
}
```

Comment: So as per your project specification at what moment the payment is treated as successful? It's not a programming, but a business problem, and you should ask the domain expert for that.